# Add a people group attribute in list programatically

Tags: development, list

I want to add a attribute (Person or Group)  in List through coding,
does any one know how to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[[Saboor](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/2799/saboor-awan)'s comment re-posted as an answer, with minor modifications]*

```
SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
  SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
  SPList list = lists['Guid for List'];
  list.Fields.Add("people", SPFieldType.User, false);
  list.Update();
}
```

Comment: Thanx. Remember to mark answers made on behalf of others as CW

Answer (score -2):

```
Itm["AssignedTo"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(Vti, "");
```

here `vti` is **USserID** or **GroupID**

Comment: Actually, I have created a list and wanted to add a column in it of people group type, not want to set values in it.

Comment: SPField Field = null;
Field = currentWeb.Fields[FName];
List.Fields.Add(Field);